# DXA caching binaries and static content

Tags: dxa, 2013-sp1, dxa-java, dxa-1.2

We are using DXA and publishing all to broker DB including binaries. When I make updates to binaries like csv file, the content is not getting reflected immediately. Same thing happens for the static content which are published embbedded on a page. Sometime i have to recycle the JVM

How long does DXA cache the binaries and other content. Where do we find these setting? How to change the same.

Answer (score 3):

For changing the cache settings, you need to look into the `ehcache.xml` of your web application. If you have Tridion object cache being turned on, you will have to look into the settings in your `cd_storage.xml`.

DXA 1.2 Java does not set cache headers as well for some browsers. See open issue [HERE](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/issues/6). It was resolved with 1.3 release.